# How to format csv files in R

Tags: r, csv

Currently I am having difficulty formatting data in R, as the data I'm trying to record seems to use 113 columns instead of rows.
When I print it in r, it looks like this:

```
           single.single_one_count1 single.single_one_count2 single.single_one_count3
file_name1                        9                       15                        6
file_name2                        9                       15                        6
file_name3                        9                       15                        6
file_name4                        9                       15                        6
file_name5                        9                       15                        6
file_name6                        9                       15                        6
file_name7                        9                       15                        6
file_name8                        9                       15                        6
           single.single_one_count4 single.single_one_count5 single.single_one_count6
file_name1                       10                        8                       11
file_name2                       10                        8                       11
file_name3                       10                        8                       11
file_name4                       10                        8                       11
file_name5                       10                        8                       11
file_name6                       10                        8                       11
file_name7                       10                        8                       11
file_name8                       10                        8                       11
           single.single_one_count7 single.single_one_count8 single.single_one_count9
file_name1                       12                        8                       10
file_name2                       12                        8                       10
file_name3                       12                        8                       10
file_name4                       12                        8                       10
file_name5                       12                        8                       10
file_name6                       12                        8                       10
file_name7                       12                        8                       10
file_name8                       12                        8                       10
           single.single_one_count10 single.single_one_count11
file_name1                        11                         4
file_name2                        11                         4
```

I wish for it to be formatted as

```
filename, value
filename2, value2
```

if that makes sense.
Here is the code used to achieve said results

```
#set the directory containing the TSV files
directory <- "C:/Users/tcamp/OneDrive/Desktop/a2_Tom_Campbell_40332657/images"

#Use list.files() to get a list of all TSV files in the directory
file_names <- list.files(directory, pattern = "\\.tsv$", full.names = TRUE)

#function definition to calculate the single_one_count
single_one_count <- function(file_name){
  #Read in the TSV file as a data frame
  df <- read.table(file_name, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
  
  #Calculate the number of rows with just one "1"
  count <- sum(apply(df == 1, 1, all))
  
  return(count)
}

result_list <- lapply(file_names, single_one_count)

result_df <- data.frame(file = c(file_name = file_names), single = c(single_one_count = result_list))

result_df

write.csv(result_df, file = "C:/Users/tcamp/OneDrive/Desktop/a2_Tom_Campbell_40332657/40332657_features.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please confirm that you are intentionally _discarding_ the "count#" from your data. For instance, if we do something like `transform(quux, rowname = rownames(quux)) |> reshape2::melt("rowname")`, we'll see that the second column includes `"single.single_one_count2"`. You're saying that you don't need any of that information? Just (for one row) something like `data.frame(rowname = "file_name1", value = 9L)`?

Comment: Hi there, I am intentionally discarding the count# from my data

Comment: Please post a **small, reproducible sample** of your dataset so we can assess the situation accurately.

Comment: It looks like the frame in the first code block of your question is the incorrect output from your intended code. This is useful, but since we don't know what the input data looks like, it's difficult to know for certain what is going on. Please provide either (1) the first few _raw_ lines of a text file, before `read.table`; or (2) the results of `read.table` on one such file.